# div любой формы

Tags: css, css3

Возможно ли сделать  `div блок` таких форм?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно сделать SVG любой формы.

Comment: Через `clip-path` это делается.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такие штуки, к сожалению, с помощью css не нарисовать - придётся использовать svg (для примера сделал одну картинку):

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="228.000000pt" height="272.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 228.000000 272.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,272.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#ff0000" stroke="none">
<path d="M1335 2691 c-66 -30 -101 -67 -174 -184 -38 -62 -84 -126 -103 -144
-75 -72 -183 -94 -368 -73 -135 14 -194 4 -244 -44 -62 -59 -100 -211 -77
-314 6 -28 34 -107 63 -174 44 -106 52 -134 56 -205 6 -106 -9 -137 -124 -263
-112 -123 -173 -210 -240 -343 -110 -218 -140 -357 -110 -508 23 -111 65 -197
129 -263 170 -174 340 -129 483 128 96 173 203 269 300 269 82 0 130 -60 209
-262 52 -134 99 -209 156 -251 99 -71 192 -64 302 22 119 94 268 420 255 557
-7 66 -32 112 -109 197 -178 196 -154 317 89 450 280 153 399 276 438 452 20
88 14 193 -15 256 -22 50 -88 111 -148 138 -73 32 -110 27 -210 -31 -104 -60
-145 -75 -177 -67 -32 8 -36 22 -47 155 -17 206 -68 365 -145 451 -63 70 -117
84 -189 51z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Есть [неплохой генератор png to svg](https://convertio.co/ru/png-svg/), но лучше проверять качество после преобразования - сложные картинки могут быть отрисованы не очень.

Comment: Но я же не смогу внутри разместить `div` элементы

Comment: Спасибо. Через `clipPath` все получилось.